# Fixing the position of CListBox relative to the visible client area, regardless of the scroll position in CScrollView

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

In an MFC SDI project using `CScrollView`, can we make a `CListBox` move as the mouse scrolls so that the listbox appears in the same position(relative to the visible client area) even if the user scrolls up or down?

For example, the menu bar(File/Edit/View/Help/etc) appears always, even if the user scrolls down. I want to make the listbox located like that. But as far as I know, there's no way to move `CListBox` after it's created with the initial position eg. in the `OnCreate()`.

If it's not possible, is there a way to achieve a similar effect?

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know MFC, but you can move any Windows control. Given MFC is a framework built around wrapping these controls, I don't see why it would be an issue. You just need to find the window rect relative to whatever window owns the scroll view. Make adjustments as necessary to position the window correctly within the scroll view in response to scroll messages. This does seem clunky though, and might have annoying edge cases. If you want the window to float, why not parent it to a different control and ensure it's at the top of the z-order?

Comment: @paddy Thank you. The method in your last sentence seems great. Could you hint at how to achieve that? If it's too much to write in a comment, an answer would be greatly appreciated, or any link would be helpful, too.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos -- I believe `CWnd` provides a wrapper for this: `CWnd::SetWindowPos`

Comment: Why not simply put it on a toolbar or dialog-bar instead? Like a toolbar button. Otherwise it will be looking weird (very unusual) and will be hiding part of the view, potentially containing useful or crucial information - this can be even annoying.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Could you suggest a simple example code? I don't know about toolbar or dialog-bar. Is it possible to put listboxes on them?

Comment: Sorry, I have no suggestions for sample code, but you can experiment creating test-projects with VS, in various UI styles and configurations. You want a project creating a `CMFCToolBar` toolbar (offering a lot more features than `CToolBar`, which encapsulates a Win32 toolbar). With `CMFCToolBar` toolbars you can use the `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton` class, to add a combo-box item (I think you have to call the `ReplaceButton()` method). Check also the `CMFCToolBarMenuButton` class. Win32 toolbars on the other hand may contain buttons with the `BTNS_DROPDOWN` style, may be a good fit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of making a CListBox appear at the same position relative to the visible client area, regardless of the vertical scrolling of the main window (MFC SDI project using CScrollView).

```
void CmyprojectView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC) {

    RECT r;
    // screen coord. (relative to the upper-left corner of the monitor)
    m_myListbox.GetWindowRect(&r);
    // screen coord -> client coord, relative to the upper-left corner of the 'visible' client area. 
    // (Note that `this` indicates the (instance of) View class)
    this->ScreenToClient(&r); 
    // Again, relative to the upper-left corner of the visible client area.
    m_myListbox.SetWindowPos(&wndTop, r.left, 100, r.right-r.left, r.bottom-r.top, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOZORDER);

}
```

Thanks to @paddy's comments.

Edit1: Strangely, this code works with one listbox, but if another listbox is added in the above code, somehow all controls including the two listboxes become invisible when I scroll to the top. I thought the `&wndTop` argument is related to this phenomenon, but if I change it to `&wndTopMost`, the positions of the listboxes are not changed at all. Any advice would be appreciated.

Edit2: Somehow the invisible problem described in the Edit1 is solved if `SWP_NOZORDER` option is added in the last argument of the `CWnd::SetWindowPos`, i.e. change `SWP_SHOWWINDOW` to `SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOZORDER`. But, as @IInspectable commented, calling `SetWindowPos` in `OnDraw` doesn't seem to be a proper way.

Comment: Re-positioning a control in a `WM_PAINT` handler is a rather odd choice. That is not how the system is intended to be used. I'm sure, the *real* problem has a different solution (like, not placing a control in a `CScrollView` when that window is not intended be scrolled with the view).

Comment: @IInspectable I guess you're right. Strangely enough, all windows become invisible if I use two listboxes in the above code and scroll to the top. The code worked well with one listbox though. I wonder why this is. Also, could you explain your different solution a bit? (not placing a control in a `CScrollView` when that window is not intended to be scrolled with the view)

Comment: Make your `CScrollView` a `CView`, make the `CListBox` a child of it, and add another `CScrollView` child to cover the remaining width or height of the parent. The list box remains stationary while the scrollable view is scrollable. No other code required.